# line segment intersection algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry, glm-math

I am following the book "Introduction to Algorithms" to implement the line segment intersection and I am confused with the result I am getting with the algorithm. I must be missing something within the algorithm and I need some help to find it. Check the following snippet of code:

```
glm::i16vec2 contourLineStart(1057,1762);
glm::i16vec2 contourLineEnd(1057,0);

glm::i16vec2 hilbertLineStart(-1762,-2466);
glm::i16vec2 hilbertLineEnd(-1734,-2466);
```

As you can see that two lines are formulated with the coordinates defined above and you can also imagine that the contourLine is formulated by contourLineStart and contourLineEnd , whereas hilbertLine can be formulated by hilbertLineStart and hilbertLineEnd. And there is no way these two lines can intersect. Unfortunately the algorithm is telling me that there is an intersection and confusing me a lot. Here goes the rest of the code:

```
glm::i32 direction(const glm::i16vec2& pi,
                   const glm::i16vec2& pj,
                   const glm::i16vec2& pk)
{
    return ((pk.x - pi.x)*(pj.y - pi.y)) - ((pj.x - pi.x)*(pk.y - pi.y));
}

int main()
{
   glm::i16vec2 contourLineStart(1057,1762);
   glm::i16vec2 contourLineEnd(1057,0);

   glm::i16vec2 hilbertLineStart(-1762,-2466);
   glm::i16vec2 hilbertLineEnd(-1734,-2466);

   glm::i16 d1 = direction(contourLineStart,contourLineEnd,hilbertLineStart);
   glm::i16 d2 = direction(contourLineStart,contourLineEnd,hilbertLineEnd);
   glm::i16 d3 = direction(hilbertLineStart,hilbertLineEnd,contourLineStart);
   glm::i16 d4 = direction(hilbertLineStart,hilbertLineEnd,contourLineEnd);


   if((d1 > 0 && d2 < 0) || (d1 < 0 && d2 > 0) &&
      (d3 > 0 && d4 < 0) || (d3 < 0 && d4 > 0))
   {
    std::cout << "There is a intersection" << std::endl;
   }
   else
   {
    std::cout << "There is no intersection" << std::endl;
   }

return 0;
}
```

Is there anything I am missing in the process ?

Thanks

Comment: Coding questions are off-topic here, so I'm moving this to Stack Overflow.  You should start by trying to debug the code: execute the code by hand, seeing what happens at each line, and check whether it makes sense or not.  I am pretty suspicious about using 16-bit integers here; seems like it's just asking for integer overflow.

Comment: I'm not a C++ expert, but expect that because you appear to be doing arithmetic on 16-bit integer types (guessing that's what `i16` means), intermediate results are overflowing. Try casting an operand of each multiplication to a 32-bit int.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, simple int worked fine. I believe that you were right about 16-bit integer. I redeclared them as simple int and now the intersection tests seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
if((d1 > 0 && d2 < 0) || (d1 < 0 && d2 > 0) &&
  (d3 > 0 && d4 < 0) || (d3 < 0 && d4 > 0))
```

Add some parentheses to avoid the ambiguity of `(a || b && c || d)`:

```
if(((d1 > 0 && d2 < 0) || (d1 < 0 && d2 > 0)) &&
  ((d3 > 0 && d4 < 0) || (d3 < 0 && d4 > 0)))
```